# ¿Cuál es el metodo equivalente de trim para String en Swift 2?

Tags: swift, string

Cual es el metodo equivalente a `Trim` de `String` en `Swift 2`, por ejemplo:

```
let string = " prueba ".trim()
// string == "prueba"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Nota:** Respuesta obtenida de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string/26797958#26797958) de [Sivanraj M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388834/sivanraj-m) a esta pregunta: [Does swift has trim method on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string/26797958)

Puedes utilizar `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` de esta forma:

```
let myString = "  prueba  "
let trimmedString = myString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
) // devuelve "prueba"
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Nota:** Respuesta obtenida de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string/26797958#26797958) de [Sivanraj M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388834/sivanraj-m) a esta pregunta: [Does swift has trim method on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string/26797958)

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
let cadenaTexto = "  \t\t  Let's trim all the whitespace  \n \t  \n  "
let cadenaTextoRecortada = cadenaTexto.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
)
// Retornará "Let's trim the whitespace"
```